# Moodle 4.0 problems with Moove 3.11.05 theme (the site is not showing breadcrumbs)

Tags: moodle, moodle-theme

Basically I've installed the Moove 3.11.05 theme and everything seems to work except the breadcrumbs. I've done the research and didn't find any solution. Has someone else encountered this problem and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moove for Moodle 4.0 is already available. You can donwnload it from its page: https://moodle.org/plugins/theme_moove/versions

Answer (score 0):

There are significant changes to the user interface in Moodle 4.0 - many of which will require changes to any custom / third-party theme.

If you want to use any such themes with Moodle 4.0, then the best advice would be to hold off upgrading until the maintainer of that theme has released a Moodle 4.0 version.

In the meantime, you may find some useful information at: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_4.0_developer_update